# How do I get the context from within an activity class?

Tags: android, android-studio

While I'm trying to initialize `context` using `getActivity()`, Android Studio shows an error "could not resolve symbol". How do I get the context from within an activity class?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Don't use `getActivity`. Use `this`.

For example:

```
Context context = this;
```

`getActivity()` is used if you are inside fragment. In an activity, you can get by using the `this` keyword.

By the way, inside an activity, you don't need to use `context`, `getSharedPreferences()` method is already present in `Activity`. Simply call `getSharedPreferences()` method without `context` reference.

Comment: getSharedPreferences requires an argument

Answer (score 1):

```
private void saveScore() {
    Context context = FullscreenActivity.this;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key),  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```