# How to save a ByteArray in the internal storage in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, file, kotlin

I'm trying to save a file containing a ByteArray in the internal storage of my Android in Kotlin, but every example I find is always telling me to use this:

```
val file = File(context.filesDir, name)
```

But `context` isn't defined, and idk what it's suposed to be. What's the supposed definition of the var context?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503168/how-do-i-get-the-context-from-within-an-activity-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace context with this.getApplicationContext()

```
val file = File(this.getApplicationContext().filesDir, name)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue. Also, is `this.applicationContext` the same that `this.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Yes Kotlin is nicely less verbose

Comment: Perfect, that's amazing! Thanks for spending time to solve my doubts. ^^